# Change x-axis from 0-6 to Mon-Sun in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib and am trying to plot some numbers by weekday. Right now (see image below), my x axis is numbered as 0 - 6, and 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday etc. How do I change the xaxis ticker label so that it says Mon, Tue, Wed etc, instead of 0-6?  Thanks a lot!

My current code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(wp.values(),'o')
```

My current image output 
[image: Current output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `Axes.set_xticklabels`:

```
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(\
    ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']);
```